# How can I get the name of a ForeignKey relation from one model to another in django?

Tags: django, django-models

Assuming we know a ForeignKey field exists on one known arbitrary model that references another, how do we find the name of this relationship?

I am looking for something like:

```
Spam.field_relating_to(Egg)
```

that would return `u'egg'` where `Spam` looks something like this:

```
from django.db import models

class Spam(models.Model)
    egg = models.ForeignKey(Egg)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To follow up on [Max Peterson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8836528/255918), here is code you could use:

```
class RelationshipMixin(object):
    def field_relating_to(other):
        for field in self._meta.fields:
            if hasattr(field, 'rel') and field.rel.to == other:
                return field.name
        return None

class Spam(models.Model, RelationshipMixin):
    egg = models.ForeignKey(Egg)
```

and then

```
>>> Spam.field_relating_to(Egg)
```

should work.

Note that this might match one-to-one and many-to-many relationships as well, so if that's important to check for you'll have to change the code somewhat.

Haven't tested it, so double check.

Answer (score 4):

Find the first field in Spam._meta.fields that has a rel.to Egg